# Reset and change Google Drive credentials

Tags: r, rgee

I'd like to change `Google Drive credentials` after `ee_Initialize(drive = TRUE)`. I install again `rgee` and `ee_install()` but not new credential in `Tidyverse API Packages` was demand.

Please, any help to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you find the credential path:

```
library(rgee)
ee_path <- path.expand("~/.config/earthengine/credentials")
ee_path
[1] "C:/Users/fores/Documents/.config/earthengine/credentials"
```

Them you remove all the content inside 'earthengine' directory and `ee_Initialize(drive = TRUE)` again. Problem solved!!